# How to handle both float and array input in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to write a function that accepts either a float OR an array of floats, and handles both of them using the same lines of code. For example, I want to return the float itself if it's a float, and the sum of the array of floats if it's an array. Something like this

```
def func(a):
  return np.sum(a)
```

and have both `func(1.2)` return 1.2, and `func(np.array([1.2,1.3,1.4])` return 3.9.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to make sure the input is a NumPy array is to use `np.asarray()`:

```
import numpy as np

def func(a):
  a = np.asarray(a)
  return np.sum(a)

func(1.2)
# 1.2
func([1.2, 3.4])
# 4.6
func(np.array([1.2, 3.4]))
# 4.6
```

or, if you want to get `len()` of your array, make sure it is at least 1-dimensional, use `np.atleast_1d()`:

```
def func(a):
  a = np.atleast_1d(a)
  return a.shape[0]

func(1.2)
# 1
func([1.2, 3.4])
# 2
func(np.array([1.2, 3.4]))
# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This already works, where's the problem?

```
import numpy as np
def func(a):
  return np.sum(a)
print(func(np.array([1.2,2.3,3.2])))
print(func(1.2))
```

Output:

```
6.7
1.2
```

Comment: You're right. Actually the problem I was facing before was that I was trying to return the length rather than the sum, and it gave me an error that floats don't have a 'len' property. Sorry, I should've included that. Do you know how to handle that?

Comment: Can you please update your question to reflect that? Including the error message will help as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use argument flattening:

```
def func(*args):
    # code to handle args
    return sum(args)
```

Now the following have the same behaviour:

```
>>> func(3)
3
>>> func(3, 4, 5)
12
>>> func(*[3, 4, 5])
12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input is a float, and then put it in a list before processing the sum:

```
def func(a):
    if isinstance(a, float):
        a = [a]
    return np.sum(a)
```

Comment: This is too restrictive. What if the user passes in an `int`, or anything else that supports addition?

Comment: In the general case we might want to restrict the types, it depends on what the function does. But yes, if we want to do so the code should check the types properly.